# Kiba-etl Mutliple Transformation-Multiple Destination

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, rubygems, etl, kiba-etl

I am trying to having mutliple transformation ,distributing it to multiple destination .
for example :

```
orginal.csv: 
title 
movies1
movies2
movies3
movies4
```

adding to the .themoviedb and it is transformed to this

```
better_movies.csv:
title
movies1=9
movies2=5.5
movies3=7
movies4=8
```

Again i want to transform and push this file to s3 
    rated_movies.csv:
    movies1=9
    movies=8

this should be the output 
how can i do this and then push it to my s3 folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Based from your question title it's not clear exactly what you are asking for, could you clarify?

If we imagine that you have a source file (CSV) which is transformed by your transforms, then written as a target file (CSV again), which you'd like to send to S3, one way would be to use a `post_process` block to act on the target file once it's ready.

Roughly it would give :

```
source CSVSource, file: my_source_file

transform
transform
transform

destination CSVDestination, file: my_target_file

post_process do
  # send your file to s3, by shelling out to `aws s3 cp`
  # (but make sure to check the exit code if you do so!)
  # or by using the AWS ruby SDK
end
```

There are of course many other possibilities, such as adding a new destination below the first one.

Hope this helps!